# SharePoint 2013- How update multiple list item using sharepoint designer workflow?

Tags: office-365, designer-workflow, workflow-activity, office, designer

I have created a list workflow and want to update multiple item update(***By using Update list item action***) in a list on specific condition but only one item is updating . Is It possible to update multiple list item ?

please suggest me a solution for this.

Comment: This may help; http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/174470/sharepoint-2013-how-update-multiple-list-item-using-sharepoint-designer-worlflo